# jQuery foreach list is not showing values

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to crate a number of selector tags programmatically. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var heading = ["Category", "Status"];       
  $.each(heading , function(key,val) { 
    $("area_"+val).hide();

  });
}
```

What I want to see as a result is:

```
$(#area_Category).hide();
$(#area_Status).hide();
```

Comment: You're missing the `#` in the selector: `$("#area_"+val).hide();`

Comment: OK, thanks , corrected that, but it still does not work. When I alert this with alert($("#area_"+val)); then I get the alert [object Object]

Comment: That is to be expected, since it is a jQuery object

Comment: ran it with just one item in the array and it worked, so I am actually not creating two lines of output if I have two items in the array it seems

Comment: Karl-Andre, got it working, run it with one item in array and it worked , then added the second and it worked too for some reason. If you want to mark your first comment as answer then I will tick it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it is your mean, Your code is right, see in the following example

```js
function hide_p(){
var heading = ["Category", "Status",  "test1",  "test2"];       
  $.each(heading , function(key,val) { 
    $("#area_"+val).hide();

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<p id="area_Category">category</p>
<p id="area_Status">Status</p>
<p id="area_test1">test1</p>
<p id="area_test2">test2</p>
<button  onclick="hide_p()">hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to write # before the selector :
 $("#area_"+val).hide();

Comment: Hi Javad, this has already been resolved, now I can run the code with just one item in the array, but as soon as I add a second then it stops working